# Search elements in array for specific text and compare to another cell outside array

Tags: arrays, google-apps-script, google-sheets, operator-precedence

I am looking for help with comparing a cell inside of an array to say a specific word and if that word is said, to check if another corresponding cell contains a string. (In this case, "Apple" is the specific word and the type of apple is listed as "Golden".) I do not know how many users there are so this helps check for each valid user in a row as well.

In this example, I am looking at users inputting three fruit choices and if they specify `Apple`, `Pear`, `Banana`, or `Plum` they must fill out the corresponding cells to say what type depending on whether it was their first, second or third choice. Some of the selected keywords may appear in other choices such as `Apple` appearing as a first choice for `Jessica` but third choice for `John`. We don't care if it appears in the second or third choice. Only care about the following choices: `Apple` must be first choice, `Pear` must be first choice, `Banana` must be second choice, and `Plum` must be third choice. I will then have a script validate whether that the information is true or false.

Below is what I am referring to:

```
Name    Fruit 1 Fruit 2 Fruit 3
Joanne  Pear    Orange  Kiwi
John    Berries Peach   Apple
Juno    Tomato  Grapes  Lemon
Jessica Apple   Banana  Pomegranate


(Type of Apple)  =  Golden  
(Type of Pear)   =  Barley  
(Type of Banana) =      
(Type of Plum)   =
```

In the image above, "Banana" was listed as Jessica's second choice of fruit but there it is not filled out below in "Type of Banana" so this should return false. If Banana contained a random string and since one of the users lists it as his or her second choice, this would have returned true.

Here is the code I have been trying but it constantly returns false and I do not know why:

```
function validateInfo() {
  var data = SpreadsheetApp.getActive().getSheetByName('Sheet1')
      .getDataRange().getValues();
  Logger.log(data[8][2]);
  var valid = true,
      notBlank;
  data.slice(8).every(function(row) {
    notBlank = row[1].toString().length;
    if (notBlank) {
      valid = (row[2] === 'Apple' && data[0][6].toString().length > 0 || row[2] === 'Pear' && data[1][6].toString().length > 0  || row[3] === 'Banana' && data[2][6].toString().length > 0 || row[4] === 'Plum' && data[3][6].toString().length > 0);
    }
    return (notBlank && valid);
  });
  Logger.log(valid);
}
```

[Link to the sheet](https://docs.google.com/spreadsheets/d/1JdY57rC61D9q7DicWS_JBBZAazEEG0XB5xjfAVnikA0/edit#gid=0).

Comment: Provide [mcve].

Comment: Welcome. I'm trying to get my head around this. FWIW,  Jessica's 2nd choice of fruit is **NOT** `Banana` but `Bananas`. Is this a typo?

Comment: I second the request by @TheMaster. You need to edit your question to provide more information. You have given an incomplete description of what your spreadsheet is endeavouring to achieve; it's not clear whether the "Type of xxxx" fields should be in Column 1 or column 1 and 2; you haven't shown what a successful outcome would look like. I wonder whether you developed this code, or perhaps you got it from another source? If from another source, please provide a link. And please share your spreadsheet.

Comment: Hi TheMaster and Tedinoz, I have edited the typo for banana. The goal is to return true or false for each choice in each row. So for Joanne, none of the choices are required so her output would be [true, true, true], for John: [true, true, true] because we don't care for apple being a 3rd choice, for Juno: [true, true, true], and for Jessica: [true, false, true]  because apple passed as first choice but banana did not. I want to use the splice() function but it seems to keep on returning false

Comment: Almost certainly your issue is the mixed usage of `&&` and `||` without explicit consideration of operator precedence. When you mix these operators, be sure to include relevant parentheses so that you are certain the expression is interpreted correctly by both **you** and the javascript runtime. Better yet, break long expressions apart if possible, so you can use expressive names to convey additional intent.

Comment: Hi Tehhowch, are you referring to valid = ((row[2] === 'Apple' && data[0][6].toString().length > 0) || (row[2] === 'Pear' && data[1][6].toString().length > 0)  || (row[3] === 'Bananas' && data[2][6].toString().length > 0) || (row[4] === 'Plum' && data[3][6].toString().length > 0)); I tried this and it didn't help me either. Still kept returning false. Can you help me understand further or correct me if I am wrong?

Answer (score 0):

**Problem**

The OP's code was constantly returning false. In addition, based on my own testing, the code was not assessing each person, nor evaluating the fruit choices accurately.

**Cause**

- It appears that `every(function(row)` was not working effectively. This was replaced with a simple "for" loop
- There were three choices of fruit, but the IF statement did not evaluate each option effectively. Since any choice of fruit could appear in any one of three fields, the value of each fruit field needed to be assessed against the master list of fruit.

**Code**

- It was not clear what action was to be taken to update any missing Fruit varieties. I have simply inserted "TBA" in the field, the OP can choose their preferred action.
- There are four sets of IF statements for each row. I'm not convinced that this is the most efficient of solutions, but it *does work*.

---

```
function so5480624202() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get data range and values
  var range = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var data = range.getValues();

  // define variables and existing values for the fruit types
  var appletype = data[0][6];
  var peartype = data[1][6];
  var bananatype = data[2][6];
  var plumtype = data[3][6];
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: apple type: "+appletype+"("+appletype.toString().length+"), pear type: "+peartype+"("+peartype.toString().length+"), banana type: "+bananatype+"("+bananatype.toString().length+"), plum type:"+plumtype+"("+plumtype.toString().length+")");//DEBUG

  // define variables
  var valid = true,
    notBlank;

  // slice the data from the eight row to thr end.
  var newdata = data.slice(8);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: newdata length: "+newdata.length);//DEBUG

  // Loop through the sliced rows
  for (x = 0; x < newdata.length; x++) {
    // check the length of the name; if name - 0, then row is blank
    notBlank = newdata[x][1].toString().length;

    // define the fruittypes for this person
    var fruittype1 = newdata[x][2];
    var fruittype2 = newdata[x][3];
    var fruittype3 = newdata[x][4];
    // Logger.log("DEBUG: Loop#:"+x+" Name:"+newdata[x][1]+" Fruits: "+fruittype1+", "+fruittype2+", and "+fruittype3);//DEBUG

    // if there is a name
    if (notBlank) {

      // test for "Apple"
      if (fruittype1 == "Apple" || fruittype2 == "Apple" || fruittype3 == "Apple") {

        // the Person has chosen an Apple
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an apple in this row"); //DEBUG

        // if the appletype has a value
        if (appletype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the apple type, so do nothing");//DEBUG
        } else {
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the apple type, so something");//DEBUG
          data[0][6] = "TBA";
        }
      } else {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no Apple chosen in this row - ignore Apple Type\n"); //DEBUG
      }

      // test for Pear
      if (fruittype1 == "Pear" || fruittype2 == "Pear" || fruittype3 == "Pear") {

        // the Person has chosen a Pear
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a pear in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the peartype has a value
        if (peartype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the Pear type, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the pear type, so something");// DEBUG
          data[1][6] = "TBA";
        }
      } else {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no pear chosen in this row - ignore Pear Type\n");//DEBUG
      }


      // test for Banana
      if (fruittype1 == "Banana" || fruittype2 == "Banana" || fruittype3 == "Banana") {
        // the Person has chosen a Banana
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a banana in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the banana type has a value
        if (bananatype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing  
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the banana type, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the banana type, so something"); //DEBUG
          data[2][6] = "TBA";
        }
      } else {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no banana chosen in this row - ignore Banana Type\n");
      }


      // Test for Plum 
      if (fruittype1 == "Plum" || fruittype2 == "Plum" || fruittype3 == "Plum") {
        // the Person has chosen a Plum
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a plum in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the plum type has a value
        if (plumtype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the plum type, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          // Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the plum type, so something"); //DEBUG
          data[3][6] = "TBA";
        }
      } else {
        // Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no Plus chosen in this row - ignore Plum Type\n");
      }
    } else {
      // Logger.log("this item must be blank");
    }

  }

    // Update values
  range.setValues(data);

}
```

---

**ADDENDUM**
I misunderstood the OP's objective. The OP wishes to *return "false" overall or return "true" if the statement is met for each element in the array.* The following modification is made purely to satisfy that requirement.

---

```
function so5480624203() {

  // setup spreadsheet
  var ss = SpreadsheetApp.getActiveSpreadsheet();

  // get data range and values
  var range = ss.getSheetByName('Sheet1').getDataRange();
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: the range is "+range.getA1Notation());//DEBUG
  var data = range.getValues();

  // define variables and existing values for the fruit types
  var appletype = data[0][6];
  var peartype = data[1][6];
  var bananatype = data[2][6];
  var plumtype = data[3][6];
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: apple type: "+appletype+"("+appletype.toString().length+"), pear type: "+peartype+"("+peartype.toString().length+"), banana type: "+bananatype+"("+bananatype.toString().length+"), plum type:"+plumtype+"("+plumtype.toString().length+")");//DEBUG

  // define variables
  var valid = true,
    notBlank;
  var mismatch = 0;
  // slice the data from the eight row to thr end.
  var newdata = data.slice(8);
  //Logger.log("DEBUG: newdata length: "+newdata.length);//DEBUG

  // Loop through the sliced rows
  for (x = 0; x < newdata.length; x++) {
    // check the length of the name; if name - 0, then row is blank
    notBlank = newdata[x][1].toString().length;

    // define the fruittypes for this person
    var fruittype1 = newdata[x][2];
    var fruittype2 = newdata[x][3];
    var fruittype3 = newdata[x][4];
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: Loop#:"+x+" "+newdata[x][1]+" Fruits: "+fruittype1+", "+fruittype2+", and "+fruittype3);//DEBUG

    // if there is a name
    if (notBlank) {
      //if (mismatch !=0) { break;}
      // test for "Apple"
      if (fruittype1 == "Apple" || fruittype2 == "Apple" || fruittype3 == "Apple") {

        // the Person has chosen an Apple
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an apple in this row"); //DEBUG

        // if the appletype has a value
        if (appletype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the apple type, so do nothing");//DEBUG
        } else {
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the apple type, so something");//DEBUG
          //data[0][6] = "TBA";
          mismatch = 1;
          //Logger.log("there is a mismatch");
          break;
        }
      } else {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no Apple chosen in this row - ignore Apple Type\n"); //DEBUG
      }

      // test for Pear
      if (fruittype1 == "Pear" || fruittype2 == "Pear" || fruittype3 == "Pear") {

        // the Person has chosen a Pear
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a pear in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the peartype has a value
        if (peartype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the Pear Variety, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the Pear Variety, so something");// DEBUG
          //data[1][6] = "TBA";
          mismatch = 1;
          //Logger.log("there is a mismatch");
          break;
        }
      } else {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no pear chosen in this row - ignore Pear Type\n");//DEBUG
      }


      // test for Banana
      if (fruittype1 == "Banana" || fruittype2 == "Banana" || fruittype3 == "Banana") {
        // the Person has chosen a Banana
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a banana in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the banana type has a value
        if (bananatype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing  
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the banana type, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the banana type, so something"); //DEBUG
          //data[2][6] = "TBA";          
          mismatch = 1;
          //Logger.log("there is a mismatch");
          break;
        }
      } else {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no banana chosen in this row - ignore Banana Type\n");
      }


      // Test for Plum 
      if (fruittype1 == "Plum" || fruittype2 == "Plum" || fruittype3 == "Plum") {
        // the Person has chosen a Plum
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is a plum in this row");//DEBUG

        // if the plum type has a value
        if (plumtype.toString().length > 0) {
          // do nothing
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is an entry in the Plum variety, so do nothing\n");      
        } else {
          //Logger.log("DEBUG: there is NO  entry in the Plum variety, so something"); //DEBUG
          //data[3][6] = "TBA";  
          mismatch = 1;
          //Logger.log("there is a mismatch");
          break;
        }
      } else {
        //Logger.log("DEBUG: there was no Plum chosen in this row - ignore Plum Type\n");
      }
    } else {
      //Logger.log("DEBUG: this item must be blank");//DEBUG
    }

  }


  if (mismatch != 0) {
    // there must be a mismatch somewhere
    // return false
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: There was a mis-match somewhere, so return false");//DEBUG
    return false;
  } else {
    // there was no mismatch
    // return true
    //Logger.log("DEBUG: There was NO mis-match anywhere, so return true");//DEBUG
    return true;
  }

}
```

Comment: Hi Tedinoz, thanks for this. I do not want anything to be updated. I just want to find where the statement is invalid and break the code and return "false" overall or return  "true" if the statement is met for each element in the array. Any idea how to do this? I tried using you code but I can't break the code and return "false" when the statement is invalid. Thank you!

Comment: @Rinaj Refer Addendum to answer The changes are minor; I could have written them in a comment, but it would have been confusing. BTW, if you found this answer useful, please consider accepting it.